# Returning failure from routine

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a routine in assembly language that do string to integer conversion. But how could I return a failure? (e.g., a non-digit is seen in string) it returns the integer value into `eax`,non-zero value as I do usually isn't a nice idea why I can't differ `"0"` converted to `0` from an error. Maybe `stc` in case of failure? how do you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in assembly, being called by assembly, you have all sorts of options.

You can return an error code (0 for no error, 1 for error, or the offset in the string where the error occurred) in a register other than %eax (%ebx, %ecx, whatever -- just make sure the caller saves the register before invoking your function).

You could set a flag in %eflags, such as parity (PF). The RET instruction does not modify any flags, so clearing the flag on entry and setting it on exit will mean the flag is still set when your routine returns. Make sure to choose a flag that does not get modified in between the time you clear and set it!

You can trigger an exception (such as overflow) and let the caller catch it -- but that is a bit heavy-handed for something like string conversion. You might crash the calling application if the exception is not caught correctly.

If you want your assembly language routine to be called like a library function (that is, called via an established calling convention in an unspecified programming language), then you really have one of two options: use a global, or have the caller pass in a pointer that your routine can use to write an error code to. Check out how strtoul(3) does it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your function needs to follow traditional calling conventions or not. If it can be called by functions which you don't have assembly-level control over, e.g. C functions, then you cannot use the carry bit to indicate error because there is no way to tell the compiler to check it. It may also be best to follow calling conventions if your code will be used in many places, since all of them need to know how it returns values.

If your function is only going to be used by assembly code which you have control over, then you can return an error however you want. Setting the carry flag (`stc`) is a common choice. For example, it is used by BIOS functions, and I personally have used it before. Just be sure to clear the carry flag on success (`clc`).

Another possibility is to use two registers for the return value, one for the actual result and one for an error code. If you use `edx`, this is actually compatible with some compilers,   such as gcc, which uses `edx:eax` as the result location for 64-bit integers or structures which fit in 64 bits.

Finally, if you need to ensure compatibility with all compilers, you should have your function take an extra argument which is a pointer to the actual result, and simply return an error code. In C, this looks like this:

```c
int myFunction(int otherArguments, int *resultPointer) {
    int errorCode, result;
    ...
    *resultPointer = result;
    return errorCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you return one extra value.

Option one (in C), use a global variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int error = 0;

int String2Int(const char* s)
{
  ...
  if (some_error_condition)
    error = 1;
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int value;
  error = 0;
  value = String2Int("12g");
  if (error != 0)
    printf("error!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Option two, pass a pointer to the error variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int String2Int(const char* s, int* error)
{
  ...
  if (some_error_condition)
    *error = 1;
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int error = 0;
  int value = String2Int("12g", &error);
  if (error != 0)
    printf("error!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Option tree, return a structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct valerr
{
  int value;
  int error;
};

struct valerr String2Int(const char* s)
{
  struct valerr ve;
  ...
  if (some_error_condition)
    ve.error = 1;
  ...
  return ve;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct valerr ve = String2Int("12g");
  if (ve.error != 0)
    printf("error!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In the latter case the compiler is probably inserting an implicit parameter into `String2Int()`, pointing to `ve`, so that `return ve;` knows where to store the returned structure.